# How can I add different soft links to different directories as a single command

Tags: linux, ubuntu

For example,

I have directories as follow,

dir1
dir2
dir3

In each of these I want to add a soft link from a different mount. I normally use this with a simple
ln -s /mnt/etc/etc/etc .
This however only works if you're working with a single directory. I have started making multiple files with different links each.

Could I use a loop to enter each unique directory and run the following command inside?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you mean. I cannot comment so there is no option for clarification but looping over directories is simple:

```sh
$ for DIR in dir1 dir2 dir3; do
      cd $DIR;
      ln -s TARGET LINK_NAME;
      cd ..;
  done
```

It can b done in one line, only remove new lines; they are for better readability.